# How to put FontAwesome icons in react?

Tags: reactjs

I created one React project and I am trying to put FontAwesome icons in react project, but it is showing some syntax errors so help me to resolve this issue.

This is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "icons",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.7",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />

ReactDOM.render(<App />, element, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I am getting error like this Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

Comment: The second parameter to `render` is supposed to be the element into which the react tree gets rendered. In other words, the third parameter you gave. The icon needs to be put into the render tree of `App` somewhere.

Comment: its working fine Thank you @Kraylog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a little confused with rendering your React code into the DOM.

`React.render()` takes 2 parameters, the first is your React element, and the second is the target in your index.html file, whereas you have added 3 parameters, hence the error.

You would need to create a React stateless functional component in this scenario, called App:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And now the  jsx component is now available as per your existing code, so you can use:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Sources: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Hi @James Grimshaw I am trying to put this icon <i class="fas fa-plane-departure"></i>. But it is showing error

Answer (score 0):

If you're not rendering the icon in App, you can render it by itself directly:

```
const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />

ReactDOM.render(<div>{element}</div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But as Kraylog pointed out you are not using the ReactDOM.render method correctly. You can read about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html).

Answer (score 0):

As to your "I am getting error like this Error: Target container is not a DOM element." Error, you need to make sure that in your **index.html** file there is a div with an id of root like such `<div id="root"></div>`. ReactDOM (which is imported from `import ReactDOM from "react-dom";`) has a **render** method on it that converts your React code to plain JavaScript and then inserts it into the **real** DOM. The render method **ONLY NEEDS TWO** arguments to work, however a third argument can be used as a callback function like such `ReactDOM.render(element, container, () => console.log("Application Mounted in DOM"))`, but I've never seen anyone use the callback function. You can read more about it here on the official document website [ReactDOM.render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render), or you can watch a pretty decent video on it on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMKRGLsLizE)

---

Here are some further tips on using the icons in a reusable manner.

Follow these steps taken from the @fortawsome npmjs registry

1. Install the necessary packages for the cause

   ```
   $ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
   $ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
   $ npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome

   $ yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
   $ yarn add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
   $ yarn add @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
   ```
2. Install some MORE of the free stuff in that they were nice enough to provide :)

   ```
   $ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons
   $ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons
   $ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons
   $ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons
   ```
3. Install even more if you are a paid pro member

   ```
   $ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons
   $ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons
   $ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons
   $ npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons
   ```

---

**Usage**

Now, finally to the good part of actually using it in an application.
I'm going to create a wrapper component around it, so that it's easy to reuse the icon/component later on, and in order to do this start by creating a file called **CoffeeIcon.js**, and in that file put in something along the lines of the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCoffee } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const CoffeeIcon = props => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {props.labelText ? <label>{props.labelText}</label> : null}
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        icon={faCoffee}
        style={props.styles}
        id={props.id}
        className={props.className}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

CoffeeIcon.propTypes = {
  labelText: PropTypes.string,
  id: PropTypes.string,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  styles: PropTypes.object
};

export default CoffeeIcon;
```

If you plan on using PropTypes for type checking and validation then add it to your application like such:

`yarn add prop-types` or `npm i prop-types`

And Finally, back in your component where you desire to use it, just do the following:

1. import it and place it just below your other import statements:

   ```
    import CoffeeIcon from "../Components/CoffeeIcon";
   ```
2. Drop in the component where you desire:

   ```
   <CoffeeIcon
     styles={{ color: "maroon" }} // optional
     id={"coffee-wrapper-id" || null} // optional
     className={"coffee-wrapper-class" || null} // optional
     labelText={"Coffee Icon"} // optional
   />
   ```
3. You're done and can now **EASILY** reuse it!